# Local install of wordpress running more and slower database queries

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've recently started working on a wordpress website and have cloned the codebase and database into my local (xampp) environment. I have the site up and running identically to the live version, however it takes almost 5 minutes to load every single refresh.

I've had a look using the query monitor plugin and on the live site 360 queries run for a total load time of .71s, however on the local install 628 queries run for a total load time of 275.98s.

Under 'slow database queries' there are hundreds listed, mainly querting the wp_posts table of the database in the below format:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.ID = 96694
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

The table has about 70k entries in it. Though this may not be an optimum way of requesting data from the database, there are no real performance issues on the live site. It is just the local installation where there are extra queries and a much slower load time.

I've tried commenting out everything and systematically adding parts of the site back however it doesn't appear that there is one single problem area - it seems to be everywhere.

Is there anything this could be? How can I debug this further?

Comment: How long does your example query take if executed, say, in a MySQL client? (I'd expect it to be very fast, given that there should be an index on the wp_posts.id column...)

Comment: It takes 0.2539 seconds through phpmyadmin. On live the same query takes 0.0003 seconds

Comment: I noticed the tables where missing primary keys and indexes which I added in. After this the load time went down to around 60 seconds, still really high and still a huge amount of queries however

Comment: [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is a great, free tool for observing server behaviour under load and can help diagnose performance problems like this.